# GO GUI help (walk package)

Tags: user-interface, go

I am making a GUI for my app, using package lxn/walk.
I'm trying to figure out how to place elements by pixels. My code is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/lxn/walk"
    . "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
)

var edit *walk.Label

func main() {

    MainWindow{
        Title:   "FetchTest",
        MinSize: Size{600, 400},
        Layout:  VBox{},

        Children: []Widget{

            Label{
                AssignTo: &edit,
                Text:     "Hello",
            },

            PushButton{
                Text: "GET DATA",
                OnClicked: func() {

                },
            },
        },
    }.Run()

    edit.SetBounds(walk.Rectangle{10, 5, 50, 50})

}
```

But this doesn't work since the code that sets the position of label is not executing.
Where to use `edit.SetBounds(walk.Rectangle{10, 5, 50, 50}` so the element is shown at the given coordinates?

Comment: If you are still building UIs I found qml was a great solution. I've put a full write up on how to get developing Gui apps in go for cross compilation to Android/Windows etc here https://github.com/amlwwalker/got-qt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with walk, but maybe `MainWindow.Run()` only returns when the window is closed? You could try the approach used in the [walk "filebrowser" example](https://github.com/lxn/walk/blob/master/examples/filebrowser/filebrowser.go): call `Create` to set up the window, do any additional initialization, and then call `Run`.